# Creating Facebook Custom Audience from graph api give Error (#100) Pixel ID Required: pixel_id is required to create WCA

Tags: facebook

I want to create Custom Audience for Facebook ads using graph api but it gives me error :

> *" (#100) Pixel ID Required: pixel_id is required to create WCA "*

I am using graph api v2.3 in python.
My code for creating Facebook Custom Audience is:

```
audience = CustomAudience(parent_id= account_id)
audience[CustomAudience.Field.name]= 'DemoAudience'
audience[CustomAudience.Field.description]= "Audience Descrip"
audience[CustomAudience.Field.subtype] = 'WEBSITE'
audience[CustomAudience.Field.retention_days] ='15'
audience[CustomAudience.Field.rule] = { "url": { "i_contains": "shoes" } }
new_custom_audience = audience.remote_create()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a bug in the documentation. You need to create a pixel first and then provide that using the "pixel_id" field. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/custom-audience-website/v2.3 for more information about that pixel.

I've created a bug report for this, to indicate that the documentation is incorrect. The url of that report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1390317697957586/. Feel free to subscribe to keep updated.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have already created pixel for my Ad Account,   In facebookads api there is no attribute "pixel_id" for CustomAudience.Field  object , please provide me solution for my problem.

Comment: Can't you use `audience[CustomAudience.Field.pixel_id] = pixel_id` ?

Comment: It gives error : "audience[CustomAudience.Field.pixel_id] = <pixel_id>
AttributeError: type object 'Field' has no attribute 'pixel_id' "

Comment: That seems to indicate that the SDK you are using is wrong. What SDK are you using?

Comment: I am using facebook-python-ads-sdk   github link is https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk  and graph api version 2.3

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the SDK? It should be supported: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk/blob/487c5451d1af5eec22bff49033d782750b0c0378/facebookads/objects.py#L1639

Comment: I updated my sdk and tried but it gives error again " {"error":{"message":"(#2654) No Permission To External Event Source.: Do not have permission to the external event source (e.g. pixel, app).","type":"OAuthException","code":2654}} "

Comment: Well, in that case please check your access token is working for the ad account to which the pixel belongs.

Comment: Access token is working, after this error to check my access token I have created campaign with the same access token.

Comment: FYI: the documentation is updated to reflect the pixel_id. See https://developers.intern.facebook.com/bugs/1390317697957586/ and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/custom-audience-website/v2.3

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem today, though I was using direct queries to the graph api (i.e. not using their sdk).
Seems to be a bug in API v2.3. When I switched to 2.2 the error was gone and my audience was created successfully.
I just had a quick look into the python API. Seems like there's no option to overwrite the default api version. But editing line 134 in facebookads/api.py should do the trick.